# How do I alphabetically sort a custom object field within a NSMutable Array?

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsmutablearray

I have a custom object like:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Store : NSObject{
    NSString *name;
    NSString *address;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *name;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *address;

@end
```

I have an array of NSMutableArray (storeArray) containing Store objects:

```
store1 = [[Store alloc] init];
store1.name = @"Walmart";    
store1.address = @"walmart address here..";

store2 = [[Store alloc] init];
store2.name = @"Target";
store2.address = @"Target address here..";

store3 = [[Store alloc] init];
store3.name = @"Apple Store";
store3.address = @"Apple store address here..";

//add stores to array
storeArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[storeArray addObject:store1];
[storeArray addObject:store2];
[storeArray addObject:store3];
```

My question is how can I sort the array by the store name? I know I can sort an array alphabetically by using this line:

```
[nameOfArray sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(caseInsensitiveCompare:)];
```

How can I apply this to the store name of my Store class?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

```
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor =
    [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"name"
                                  ascending:YES
                                   selector:@selector(caseInsensitiveCompare:)];
[nameOfArray sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:@[sortDescriptor]];
```

Related documentation:

- [[NSArray sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:]](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSArray/sortedArrayUsingDescriptors%3a)
- [NSSortDescriptor](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSSortDescriptor_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Answer (score 10):

[Regexident's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8107594/how-do-i-alphabetically-sort-a-custom-object-field-within-a-nsmutable-array/8107604#8107604)  is based on NSArrays, the corresponding in-place sorting for NSMutableArray would be `-sortUsingDescriptors:`

```
[storeArray sortUsingDescriptors:
                    [NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"name" 
                                                                           ascending:YES 
                                                                            selector:@selector(caseInsensitiveCompare:)]]];
```

Now `storeArray` it-self will be sorted.

Comment: Thanks man. It's weird that they have 2 methods with different results

Comment: what do u mean? One is for in-place sorting, one creates a new array. Both versions have their own use cases.

Comment: Thank you so much...most of answers shows how to sort `NSArrays` even though it is asked for `NSMutableArray` array. This worked like a charm :)