# How to sort NSMutableArray of object in ascending or descending order

Tags: iphone, ios, nsmutablearray

I have created an NSMutableArray of Object using this code

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSArray * ary1 = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"01/07",@"02/07",@"03/07",@"04/07",@"05/07",@"06/07",@"07/07", nil];
        NSArray * ary2 = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"First",@"Second",@"Third",@"Forth",@"Fifth",@"Sixth",@"Seventh", nil];
        NSArray * ary3 = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"1000",@"2000",@"3000",@"4000",@"5000",@"6000",@"7000", nil];

tableAry = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        for (int i=0; i<ary1.count; i++) {
            //cardSummry will hold the data and give back the model to store in array and we can find that value using model
            DataModel *dataModel = [[DataModel alloc] init];
            dataModel.date = [ary1 objectAtIndex:i];
            dataModel.name = [ary2 objectAtIndex:i];
            dataModel.ammount = [ary3 objectAtIndex:i];

            [tableAry addObject:dataModel];
        }
}
```

And this is my DataModel Class

.H file

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface DataModel : NSObject

//this variable is used to get the data from array
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSString *date;
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSString *name;
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSString *ammount;

//this method will genarate a data model which will be added to array for future use
+ (id)cardSummary:(NSString*)date name:(NSString*)name ammount:(NSString*)ammount;
@end
```

.M file

```
#import "DataModel.h"

@implementation DataModel

@synthesize date,name,ammount;

//this method will genarate a data model which will be added to array for future use
+ (id)cardSummary:(NSString*)date name:(NSString*)name ammount:(NSString*)ammount
{
    DataModel *dataModel = [[self alloc] init];

    [dataModel setDate:date];
    [dataModel setAmmount:ammount];
    [dataModel setName:name];

    return dataModel;
}

@end
```

Now i want to sort it according to the name in that array i have seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8107594/how-do-i-alphabetically-sort-a-custom-object-field-within-a-nsmutable-array) Question in SO which look like mine  and use its answer code to solve my problem but it didn't work for me which is this

```
[tableAry sortUsingDescriptors:
     [NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"name" ascending:YES selector:@selector(caseInsensitiveCompare:)]]];

    NSLog(@"tableAry : %@",tableAry);
```

So how  can i sort my array

**Update**

As @Martin R And @Rick said i have alloc my array but now i got this error.

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[DataModel caseInsensitiveCompare:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7550850'

Comment: If `NSLog(@"tableAry : %@",tableAry);` shows `NULL` then you forgot to alloc+init `tableAry`.

Comment: First, correct your title, should be "sort". Next, try adding `tableAry = [NSMutableArray array];` before the for-loop in viewDidLoad. You need to initialize the NSMutableArray before adding objects to it.

Comment: @MartinR see my update i have alloc my array but ran into second error

Comment: @Rick see my update i have alloc my array but ran into second error

Comment: That's because you did not define the `caseInsensitiveCompare:` method for DataModel. `caseInsensitiveCompare` is a convenience method for NSString.

Comment: Are you sure that you posted your exact code? I tested it and it did not crash.

Comment: @Rick: That is not correct. Due to `sortDescriptorWithKey:@"name"` the  `caseInsensitiveCompare:` message is sent to each "name" property of the DataModel objects. It should just work (and it did for me :-).

Comment: @Kane: Could it be that you called `sortUsingSelector:` and not `sortUsingDescriptors:` as posted in the question?

Comment: @MartinR I am interpreting the error message.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use the `NSSortDescriptor`.

```
NSSortDescriptor* sortDes = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"your key" ascending:YES];
[_array sortUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDes]];
```

Try it.

Answer (score 2):

```
[tableAry sortUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(DataModel *obj1, DataModel *obj2) {
        return [obj1.name caseInsensitiveCompare:obj2.name];
}];
```

Comment: Your code is correct, but the code in the question should work as well.

Comment: Helped me, Great Work :)

Answer (score 1):

```
-(NSMutableArray*)sortArrayInAssendingOrder:(NSMutableArray*)array{ // array must have numerical value
NSMutableArray *newArray=[NSMutableArray arrayWithArray: array];
NSMutableArray *shortedArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
for (int i=0; i<=[newArray count]+1; i++) {
    NSInteger value_1=[[newArray objectAtIndex:0]integerValue];
    for(int j=0; j<[newArray count]; j++){
        NSInteger value_2=[[newArray objectAtIndex:j]integerValue];
        if(value_1>value_2){
            value_1 =nil;
            value_1 = value_2;
        }
    }
    [shortedArray addObject:value_1];
    [newArray removeObject: value_1];
}
    [shortedArray addObject:[newArray objectAtIndex:0]];

return shortedArray;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```
-(NSMutableArray*)shortCardInAssendingOrder:(NSMutableArray*)cardSetArr{
    NSMutableArray *shortedArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    for (int i=0; i<=[cardSetArr count]+1; i++) {
        Card *firstCard=[cardSetArr objectAtIndex:0];
        for(int j=0; j<[cardSetArr count]; j++){
            Card *nextCard=[cardSetArr objectAtIndex:j];
            if(firstCard.cardSymbol>nextCard.cardSymbol){
                firstCard=nil;
                firstCard=nextCard;
            }
        }
        [shortedArray addObject:firstCard];
        [cardSetArr removeObject:firstCard];
    }
    [shortedArray addObject:[cardSetArr objectAtIndex:0]];
    return shortedArray;
}
```

Note: you can use ur tag or any thing else at tha place of cardSymbol

Comment: How you are using > sign for NSString?
DOWNVOTE